# Can I change Control's Enable in 'envoke' in multi thread program?

Tags: c#

I have a timer in my projcet that is fires every 5 seconds. 
in this timer, I call an event (EmailTransceive) in thread.

```
private void TimerTransceiveEmail_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DamavandEmailTransceiveIsBusy)
        return;

    DamavandEmailTransceiveIsBusy = true;
    TimerTransceiveEmail.Enabled = false;

    Thread TimerTransceiveEmailThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => TransceiveEmail()));

    TimerTransceiveEmailThread.Start();
}
```

and here is TransceiveEmail method :

```
    private void TransceiveEmail()
    {
        for (int objIMAPIndex = 0; objIMAPIndex < lstObjIMAP.Count; objIMAPIndex++)
        {
            try
            {
                objIMAP[objIMAPIndex].SSLConnected(ServerIP, ServerPort);
                objIMAP[objIMAPIndex].Login(Username, Password);

                objIMAP[objIMAPIndex].IsLogin = true;

                dataGridViewIMAP.Rows[objIMAPIndex].Cells["Recieved"].Value = (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewEmailNumber.Rows[EmailAddressIndex].Cells["Recieved"].Value) + 1).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                objIMAP[objIMAPIndex].IsLogin = false;

                // log exception
            }

            if (!objIMAP[objIMAPIndex].IsConnected || !objIMAP[objIMAPIndex].IsLogin)
                continue;

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                if (dataGridViewIMAP.Rows[objIMAPIndex].Cells["RecieveTrace"].Value.ToString() == "**")
                    dataGridViewIMAP.Rows[objIMAPIndex].Cells["RecieveTrace"].Value = "--";
                else
                    dataGridViewIMAP.Rows[objIMAPIndex].Cells["RecieveTrace"].Value = "**";
            });
        }


        for (int objSMTPIndex = 0; objSMTPIndex < lstObjSMTP.Count; objSMTPIndex++)
        {
            try
            {
                lstObjSMTP[objSMTPIndex].Connect(ServerIP, ServerPort);
            }
            catch { }

            if (!lstObjSMTP[objSMTPIndex].IsConnected)
                continue;

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                if (dataGridViewIMAP.Rows[objIMAPIndex].Cells["SendTrace"].Value.ToString() == "**")
                    dataGridViewIMAP.Rows[objIMAPIndex].Cells["SendTrace"].Value = "--";
                else
                    dataGridViewIMAP.Rows[objIMAPIndex].Cells["SendTrace"].Value = "**";
            });
        }

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            TimerTransceiveEmail.Enabled = true;
        });

        DamavandEmailTransceiveIsBusy = false;
    }
```

The problem is here:
after some hours, the timer will be disable and also DamavandEmailTransceiveIsBusy will be 'True' and it wont change to 'False'. so the program dosent work properly. I really confused by this problem and I cant find any reason for that! why is it happening. can

Thanks for any helping.

Comment: You using IMAP and therefore the network. Have you set related timeouts for your network calls? Seem's TransceiveEmail does not always return.

Comment: no actually I havent set timeout for that. but I wait 1 day!! I think the It has default timeout less than 1 day! @Kevin